# OAuth 2.0 login link for partners

Tags: oauth2, partner

I am integrating Salesforce OAuth 2.0 as written [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com). The link to log is generated in the following format as expected:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_uri>
```

This generates a working link, that would start the login process and everything is working fine for "regular" users.

On the other hand, my client's link to log into Salesforce GUI looks like this:

```
https://theCompany.force.com/partner
```

So, when I get the login link described above, it does not let the user from the said company to log in.

I also tried [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/02/oauth-for-portal-users.html) solution, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several tries, the most obvious solution in the end was

```
https://theCompany.force.com/partner/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_uri>
```

This generates the login link as following:

```
https://theCompany.force.com/partner/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=<source_id>&display=popup
```

Funny how this can't be found anywhere in salesforce documentation...